# Inheritance issue C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I've got a small problem with inheritance in my application. I've got a base class Client, which has a subclass Job. Basically, I'm trying to create a constructor for Job but I'm getting an error saying "'Job_Manager_Application.Client' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"

Can't figure out why it's doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At least, you should offer a piece of code here for us to imagine the issue.

Comment: @hinkrate: The compiler message is 100% clear on this one.

Answer (score 3):

Your Client class has a constructor that takes parameters.

Therefore your Job constructor needs to pass parameters to Client.

Example:

```
class Client{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Client(string name){
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

--

```
class Job:Client{
    public double Rate {get;set;}

    public Job(double rate){
        // This won't compile, because Client won't have its "name" parameter.
    } 

    public Job(string name, double rate) : base(name){
        // So you need to pass a parameter from your Job constructor using "base" keyword.
        this.Rate = rate;
    }

    public Job(double rate) : base("Default Name"){
        // You could do this, this is legal.
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why is `Job` a subclass of a `Client`? Inheritance represents *is a* relationships (a `Cat` *is a* `Animal` so `class Cat : Animal { }`). A `Job` *is **not** a* `Client`.

Anyway, your error message is clear. You don't have an **accessible** parameterless constructor on `Client`. You need to explicitly invoke a constructor on client from a constructor on `Job` then.

```
class Client {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Client(string name) { this.Name = name; }
}

class Job : Client {
    public Job(string name) : base(name) { }
}
```

See that `base(name)` there? That is invoking the base constructor `Client.Client(string)` on `Client`. If you don't specify a base constructor explicitly, the compiler tries to find an **accessible** parameterless constructor. If there is not one, you get the compile time error that you experienced.

So, you either need to do as I've done above, which is invoke an **accessible** non-parameterless constructor explicitly, or add a parameterless constructor to `Client`.

But please, rethink your model. A `Job` is not a `Client`.

Answer (score 1):

Client has a constructor that takes arguments and you aren't calling it properly

```
public class Job
{
    public Job(int num) { }
}

public class Client : Job
{
    public Client() : base(1) {}
}
```